# enviar informacion de nodejs a angular 5

Tags: nodejs, angular5

Estoy haciendo uso de "node-dir" un modulo de nodejs para listar los subdirectorios y archivos de un folder, me gustaría saber como puedo enviar esta información hasta mi componente en angular 5. mi codigo de node es el siguiente:

```
const  dir = require('node-dir');

dir.paths('./src/uploads/', function(err, paths) {
 if (err) throw err;
 console.log('files:\n',paths.files);
 console.log('subdirs:\n', paths.dirs);
});
```

Me gustaría poder enviar el paths por http desde mi Server hasta mi componente de angular, el código funciona y logra traerme los archivos que tengo en ese directorio pero necesito el path dentro de mi componente.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema? ¿Puedes acceder a esa dirección desde tu navegador?

Comment: Debes crear un servicio en Angular y hacer las llamadas a tu servidor. Tus componentes deben usar el servicio para obtener los datos